# Core Bluetooth characteristic value write error

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I use core bluetooth with other device. I try to send the data and receive same data from peripheral. 
However, in 'writeVal:forCharacteristic:type', characteristic value was always 'null'. bellow is my code. Would you show that code and advise to solve this problem.

```
NSString *test_s = @"test";
self.sendData = [test_s dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[self.connectedPeripheral writeValue:self.sendData forCharacteristic:self.aChar type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
NSLog(@"%@", self.aChar);
```

I can show the properties of characteristic on my peripheral device.

Answer (score 0):

Core bluetooth uses delegate methods! Set your "self" to be the delegate of the connectedPeripheral and implement the peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error: method.  Check the value of the characteristic in this method (as well as the error parameter).

To effectively change the characteristic.value you would instead do:

```
[self.connectedPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:self.aChar];
```